# Getting response code as 5 in inapp billing consumption android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Actually i am trying to do In-App Purchase in android and i have downloaded the trivial drive from android sdk. I can do the purchase sucessfully by calling launchPurchaseFlow method but the problem is when i try to consume the product by calling consumeAsync method im getting the response code as 5 (Developer Errror).
this is the code i am executing after the purchase was sucessfull

```
mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_GAS), mConsumeFinishedListener);
```

anyone please provide me the solution ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are existing questions on this.  It is a temporary (we hope) but introduced around 3/8/13.  Please star and comment on this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53077.

Answer (score 13):

Developer Error (code = 5) usually means that you’re testing with an app that is either signed differently than the APK you uploaded via the Developer Console, or which has a different version/version code than the APK that you uploaded.

Per the doc (http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html):

"Invalid arguments provided to the API. This error can also indicate that the application was not correctly signed or properly set up for In-app Billing in Google Play, or does not have the necessary permissions in its manifest"

If you're testing with an APK signed with a debug key, for example, you might get this error.  It should be signed with the same key as the APK that was uploaded to the Google Play store's Developer Console for testing (typically, the key you will use for the released app).

Also, if you're testing with an APK that has a version code that differs from that of the APK presently uploaded to the Developer Console, you may receive this error code 5 (developer error).

Comment: And how can we develope/debug InApp billing? Is the first time I'm implementing it and I can't see how a developer can implement it by doing trial and error, so uploading the apk, seeing results, changing whatever is not correct, creating new apk, uploading again new version, and so on.

Comment: You can just not increase the version code on the version that you are developing until you have it debugged, so that the version code will match that of the latest version that you uploaded.  You don't have to keep uploading a new version for each change.

To use the debugger, you might have to change your debug key to the one used to sign your app, but that may be a bad idea.  Personally, I debug IAB using a version signed with my deployment key for stuff related to IAB, and skip the debugger for that part of my debugging.  It's async anyway, so using log messages works pretty well.

Comment: Excellent note about the version/version code must been the same as the apk uploaded (and published to alpha/beta). I had gradle auto incrementing the version code and got error code 5.